# Get the value-set of a map while using Collectors.groupingBy()

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, collectors

I have a `Collection<A>` that i want to group by its type. I can get the type of A via a `getType` method. The result should be of the type `Collection<Collection<A>>`. Eg:
Input: `[A1 ,A2, A3, A1, A3, A4]` (A1 is an object of type '1', so on)
Output: `[[A1, A1], [A2], [A3, A3], [A4]]`

Here's is what I've written:
`listOfAs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClass::getType)).values();`

Is there a way I can directly obtain the value-set of the map generated, instead of generating the map and then extracting the value-set from it using the `values()`?

Comment: Using a temporary map is probably the most efficient way performance wise because you have a constant time access to each type's collection - if you want to do without a map you will need to iterate over each collection for each insertion. So I don't think it would be a good idea to do what you are asking for.

Comment: @user3381995 I could be wrong but if all you care about is the values in the `Map`, why are you even creating groups in the first place? Wouldn't `listOfAs` have the same contents as the `values` in the grouped `Map`?

Comment: What do you mean with “directly obtain the value-set of the map generated”? The collection returned by `Map.values()` *is* as direct as it can be. There is no copy operation.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I'm trying to construct a collection of groups of A's from the original collection of A's. They have to be grouped based on their type. So, the **input** is not the same as the **output** (see description). Also, you seem to have wrongly inferred that I already have the `Map` - it is actually the `groupingBy` that is creating the map.

Comment: @Holger Apologies for not being clear. By 'directly' i meant by reworking the grouping logic (or using a different method altogether) so that i dont end up generating a `Map` whose key-set is of no use to me - 'directly' generating a the list I'm interested in.

Comment: The map, or the keyset of it, is what makes your grouping operation working, or at least makes it working with a reasonable performance, so it’s not really “of no use to you”. If you don’t like hashing and your grouping criteria has an order, you may sort your list by type and split into groups at type boundaries but that’s not a stream operation.

Comment: @user3381995 But after you create the `Map`, you just get the values from it so why did you group it in the first place? Once again, I may have misinterpreted something so please bare with me for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well internally you will still need to generate such map. It's possible to create a custom collector though:

```
public static <T, K> 
Collector<T, ?, Collection<List<T>>> groups(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier) {
    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier), Map::values);
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
Collection<List<SomeClass>> result = listOfAs.stream().collect(groups(SomeClass::getType));
```

Note that internally it doesn't differ much from your solution. You just incorporate the `values()` call inside the collector.

Comment: While this seems like it would work, I think I'll go with not using custom collectors since it is, like you said, essentially the same as the original solution. Itr seems like an overkill for the usecase in question.

Comment: @user3381995: sure, you're right. Such approach can be useful if you construct a downstream collector for more complex task (for example, you want to perform `groupingBy` one more time and get `Map<SomethingElse, Collection<List<SomeClass>>>`.